# Make index refer to \poemtitle (verse package) instead of page number

Tags: indexing, section-titles, verse, poetry

I try to make an “index of rhymes” in a poem collection.

So, I began to set an index called “Index of rhymes”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{verse}

\makeindex
\makeindex[name=rhymes,title=Index of rhymes]

\begin{document}
\poemtitle{The Road Not Taken}
\begin{verse}
    Two roads diverged in a yellow wood,\\ \index[rhymes]{ood}
    And sorry I could not travel both\\ \index[rhymes]{oth}
    And be one traveler, long I stood\\ \index[rhymes]{ood}
    And looked down one as far as I could\\ \index[rhymes]{ood}
    To where it bent in the undergrowth;\\ \index[rhymes]{oth}
\end{verse}

\printindex[rhymes]
\end{document}
```

And the output is this one [image: Output]

So, the the page is correctly set for each rhyme. But instead of page, I try to make it show the poem title set with `\poemtitle`.

So, is it possible to catch the last `\poemtitle`’s value and use it in the index near each rhyme instead of the page number where it’s used?

The expected rendering is something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to replace a page number in an index with something else. But have a look at this:

```
% verseindexprob.tex  SE 641848

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{verse}

\newcommand{\titletext}{}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=rhymes,title=Index of rhymes]

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\titletext}{The Road Not Taken}
\poemtitle{\titletext} % \index[rhymes]{The Road Not Taken}
\begin{verse}
    Two roads diverged in a yellow wood,\\ \index[rhymes]{\titletext!ood}
    And sorry I could not travel both\\ \index[rhymes]{\titletext!oth}
    And be one traveler, long I stood\\ \index[rhymes]{\titletext!ood}
    And looked down one as far as I could\\ \index[rhymes]{\titletext!ood}
    To where it bent in the undergrowth;\\ \index[rhymes]{\titletext!oth}
\end{verse}

Another verse\index[rhymes]{Another verse}

Set more verse\index[rhymes]{Set more verse}

Even more verse\index[rhymes]{Even more verse}

%%%%%%%% use ood and oth as major index entries and tile as subentry

\poemtitle{\titletext} % \index[rhymes]{The Road Not Taken}
\begin{verse}
    Two roads diverged in a yellow wood,\\ \index[rhymes]{ood!\titletext}
    And sorry I could not travel both\\ \index[rhymes]{oth!\titletext}
    And be one traveler, long I stood\\ \index[rhymes]{ood!\titletext}
    And looked down one as far as I could\\ \index[rhymes]{ood!\titletext}
    To where it bent in the undergrowth;\\ \index[rhymes]{oth!\titletext}
\end{verse}

\printindex[rhymes]
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are two index styles, one with the `poemtitle` as the main entry and the other with your `ood` and `oth` as main entries. Perhaps one of these is closer to what you are after.

Comment: Great. I was looking for the rhymes `ood` and `oth`as main entries. Now, I just need to hide page number.